# How to add localhost to php regex?

Tags: php, regex

I don't know how to compose regex but I need to make localhost url valid in one of the program I'm using. This is the regex the program uses to validate URL:

```
preg_match ( '/^https?:\/\/(([a-z0-9-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})(:[0-9]+)?(\/?|\/\S+)$/iu', $url )
```

My local website's root URL is `http://localhost/`, How to make it validated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regexp can be splitted in some parts:

```
https?://
(
    ([a-z0-9-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}
    |\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}
)
(:[0-9]+)?
(/?|/\S+)
```

In order to add localhost to the set of valid urls, simply add `localhost|` between those both opening brackets after the protocol.

Comment: Something to notice: Your regexp does not allow any IPv6 urls or other urls, such as I'm using `server` as internal network address.

Comment: The program I use is to fetch video or image from website. I don't know whether or not the author added some limitation to exclude some URLs. I don't know if it is safe to change to FILTER_VALIDATE_URL. Any suggestion for me?

Comment: I don't know enough of your project to decide that, but generally that might be a better idea - as long as the specific extension is available.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issue of limitation on  IPV6 or other urls, I will use filter_var then.

Answer (score 4):

I see you already have the option for an IPv4 address, so just an another option for `localhost`.

After the `\d{1,3}` chain, just before the `)`, add `|localhost`.

Answer (score 4):

I'd just add localhost as an option to the start of the pattern, so the start of it looks like this:

```
preg_match('/^https?:\/\/(localhost|([a-z0-9-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6} (the rest as before)
```